# Distributing images across container

Tags: html, css

I have a series of images I want to distribute evenly across a div. I've seen many questions similar to this with very good answers, but many use padding/margins to achieve this, which leaves empty gaps on the left and right edges of the containing div.

Right now I'm applying a margin-right to each image, which works except for the very last image, which has an ugly empty gap on its right side. I could just apply a different class to the last image with no margin, but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution. What other options do I have?

```
#photo_bar {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:785px;
}

#photo_bar a {
    margin-right:7px;
}

.photo_bar_image {
    border-radius:9px;
    background-size: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-size 0.2s, background-position 0.2s;
}

.photo_bar_image:hover {
    background-size:140px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}

<section id='photo_bar'>
    <a class='photo_bar_image'></a>
    <a class='photo_bar_image'></a>
    <a class='photo_bar_image'></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
img:last-child {
   // change the margin here!
}
```

This will be applied to the last image element in the container!

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: Nice! Very sexy solution, thanks. I definitely need to look more into these CSS selectors.